# What should I use instead of `this` inside of nested function or may I use it?

Tags: javascript

I've class in js - how I can tweak body in nested function in line #4. Im getting warning from IDE:

`Potentially invalid reference access to a class field via 'this.' of a nested function`

is there any solution to write this properly? Or I can use `this` inside nested function?

```
fetchStickyAppointment = flow(function* () {
  fetch(/api/) 
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    .then(data => { 
      if (+data?.id > 0) { 
        this.stickyAppointment = this.currentAppointment = data; 
      } else { 
        this.stickyAppointment = data; 
        this.currentAppointment = this.findCurrentAppointment(); 
      }
    }); 
})
```

Comment: Why do you need that generator function if it doesn't yield anything?

Comment: Arrow functions capture `this`, you don't need to do anything special. The IDE is wrong.

Comment: @JonasWilms its for mobx purposes

Answer (score 0):

You could assign `this` to a variable outside the function scope and then use that.

```
let self = this;
fetchStickyAppointment = flow(function* () {
  fetch(/api/) 
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    .then(data => { 
      if (+data?.id > 0) { 
        self.stickyAppointment = self.currentAppointment = data; 
      } else { 
        self.stickyAppointment = data; 
        self.currentAppointment = self.findCurrentAppointment(); 
      }
    }); 
})
```